# UI: Month selector

Tags: java, user-interface, datepicker, swt

For my UI, I need a month selector (i.e. not a day but "what happened in August 2008"). Has anyone seen such an UI element?

Obviously, I'm looking for more than two combo boxes (one for the months and one for the year). What I want to know if someone has encountered a *cool* month selector. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try jQuery UI's Datepicker, and change it to your need of only choosing month/year?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year